# Resize transparent image with Magick.NET

Tags: c#, image, magick.net

I got some weird issues when resizing an image with transparency in Magick.NET. I am using Q16-AnyCPU.

I am resizing a 100px image to 400px.

```cs
MagickImage image = new MagickImage("test.png");
image.Resize(400, 400);
image.Write("test_resized.png");
```

I have tried many combinations of `image.FilterType` and `image.Interpolate` without any good results.
Only when I use `image.AdaptiveResize(400, 400);`, it looks somewhat better, but not as expected. The final image I want to resize is much bigger and `AdaptiveResize` is very slow.

When I disable Alpha via `image.Alpha(AlphaOption.Off);` I looks quice nice, but I want to keep the alpha.

Source image (the white area is transparent):

[image: The white area is transparent]

What I get:

[image: Wrong result]

What I want:

[image: Resized with Photoshop]

Comment: Not a lot of magic at work here.  If you'd use .NET then you'd specify InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor and PixelOffsetMode.Half to get the blocky non-interpolated version of the larger image.  Whatever it takes with MagickImage, do the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to set `VirtuaPixelMethod`, thanks for the hint:

```cs
MagickImage image = new MagickImage("test.png");
image.VirtualPixelMethod = VirtualPixelMethod.Transparent;
image.Resize(400, 400);
image.Write("test_resized.png");
```